# Android: use both camera in the same time

Tags: android, camera

I want active both camera

Front for video call and back for capture images

Some devices ( Like lg g4 ) work fine, but some devices ( Like sony ) Not work and application crashing

How i can detect devices if work this item ?

```
if(CanActiveBoth){
 // show icons
} else {
 // hidden icons
}
```

Comment: Handle the exception in non working devices.

Comment: @Rohit5k2 how i can ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first you should try to catch the exceptions. Maybe you can fix this issue for all devices, of you read the StackTrace,
therefore just pass your method which crashs in a Try-Catch-Block

```
try {
     // ...your Method that crashes
} catch (Exception e) {
     // Get your Error Message (or e.getStackTrace())
     System.out.println("Error " + e.getMessage());
     return null;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. but i want get error at run application. your code for on click

Comment: if you catch the error while debugging with this code, you might get to know, what exactly the error causes --> simple example: on some devices the parameter x = null, so with this information you can go with a simple `if(x != null)` expression to check on the run, if the device can open both cameras

Comment: Is correct ? : `try {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE_SECURE);
                intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri);
                startActivityForResult(intent, 2);
}`

Comment: i think so, try it out :)

Comment: if you LG and Sony device works both (of sony does not throw an exception), you need to go deeper, and use the try catch block in the started activity